# How can I public a site in Composum platform

Tags: sling

I try to public a site in composum platform but it can not show component content.
When I access url:http://localhost:8080/content/sites/site1/home/product.html
It shows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Useno.png

When I access the http://localhost:8080/public/sites/site1/home/product.html
It shows
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH77N.png

I saw in the error.log, It display
GET /content/sites/mysite/home/test.html HTTP/1.1] com.composum.sling.cpnl.ClientlibTag No clientlib found for path 'null' / category 'composum.pages.components.view'

when I run on debug mode in file ResourceResolverImpl.java
at line 448 in getResourceInternal method the  Resource result variable always return null in the anonymous access. I think because I access by anonymous user.
This is the image when I do not login

[image]
Please help me.
Thank you